# SequenceMatcher ratio()

Tags: python, diff, difflib

I was planning to use `SequenceMatcher(...).ratio()` to check if two strings are similar. However, my quick tests returns that I didn't expect (and that won't work for my purpose):

```
>>> SequenceMatcher(None, 'abqab', 'abcab').ratio()
0.8
>>> SequenceMatcher(None, 'abqabc', 'abcabc').ratio()
0.5
```

A longer string with the same number of mistakes should have a equal or lower ratio, right?

Answer (score 0):

abc and abq are only 3 letters and nearly match so this is correct.  Longer strings that are different perform as expected.

```
>>> SequenceMatcher(None, 'abqdef', 'abcdef').ratio()
0.83333333333333337
```

Comment: So apparently one mistake in `abcabc` is different from one mistake in `abcdef`? That still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: abq matches abcabc in 2 places with one letter difference.  It matches abcdef in one place.